# Origin of the phrase ほんや(Not 本屋）

Tags: questions

A while back in high school my classes watched "My Boss My Hero," in which the main character says ほんや, it was translated as "What?" (I think.) In any case, I've never heard anything stylistically similar, so I was wondering where it came from.

Comment: I think it's closer to "huh" – it's just a sound.

Comment: 何だろう・・・「おや？」とか「ほにゃ？」って言ったのかな？

Comment: 「はにゃ？」みたいですね。http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%9E%E3%82%A4%E2%98%86%E3%83%9C%E3%82%B9_%E3%83%9E%E3%82%A4%E2%98%86%E3%83%92%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AD%E3%83%BC
語源は「おーい!はに丸」あたりかな。
http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%8A%E3%83%BC%E3%81%84!%E3%81%AF%E3%81%AB%E4%B8%B8

Comment: Just speculation, but could it be related to Osaka-ben's 本間【ほんま】, perhaps?

Comment: @Kaji:  Osaka-ben `ホンマ` would never be used for "What?".

Comment: As a literal "what", probably not, but perhaps something along the lines of "Really?", which sometimes gets used in the same manner of "Eh?" in English.

Answer (score 4):

The main character of My Boss My Hero, Sasaki Makio, says はにゃ？ as an expression when unsure or

As said in [Wikipedia](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%9E%E3%82%A4%E2%98%86%E3%83%9C%E3%82%B9_%E3%83%9E%E3%82%A4%E2%98%86%E3%83%92%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AD%E3%83%BC#.E4.B8.BB.E8.A6.81.E4.BA.BA.E7.89.A9)

```
疑問に思ったりすることがあったりすると「はにゃ?」と言うのが口癖
```

When in doubt while thinking, he says his favorite phrase, 'hanya?'

This is not a common Japanese word or saying and is unique to the character to help give him flavor.